# How to parse a class that extends from Arraylist with Moshi

Tags: android, retrofit2, moshi, data-moshing

I'm new with Moshi and I'm trying to parse the data, with Retrofit, from one class that extends an Arraylist of items and I'm getting this error:

```
  com.squareup.moshi.JsonDataException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at path $
```

Class:

```
class CarSelection: ArrayList<CarItem>()

data class CarItem(
    @field:Json(name = "type") val type: String,
    @field:Json(name = "name") val name: String,
    @field:Json(name = "color") val color: String,
    @field:Json(name = "image") val image: String
)
```

Retrofit service:

```
 fun getRemoteService(baseUrl :String, client : OkHttpClient): MyRemoteService {
            return Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(baseUrl)
                .client(client)
                .addConverterFactory(MoshiConverterFactory.create())
                .build()
                .create(MyRemoteService::class.java)
        }
```

Comment: can you add the code where you make the request to the service?

Comment: What does your JSON look like?